# if else condition in pl / sql query for many process conditions

Tags: if-statement, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have case 4 conditions, but still do not understand how to apply the if conditions.
first,
if d_user.nik is not null and d_user.full_name is not null and d_user.email is not null then
update user
else
insert user
and
if d_user.masa_kerja is not null and d_user.masa_kerja> to_date (sysdate) then
can update and insert the user
else DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Expired') or cannot be inserted and updated.
how to arrange the appropriate if conditions in order to match the process conditions ?

Comment: Could you, please, edit the question and format *pseudocode* you wrote? The way it is now, it is impossible to guess what you meant to say. I *could* edit it (I tried), but - I still don't understand what goes where. Besides, as it seems you know what you want to do, what problem do you face when you implement it? What happens when you run code that stands behind the question?

Comment: I've tried to do this,
`if d_user.nik is not null and d_user.full_name is not null and d_user.email is not null then
       if d_user.masa_kerja is not null and d_user.masa_kerja> to_date (sysdate) then
(Query Update)
else if
(Query Insert)
end if;
else
('Expired')
end if;` but what happens, if when entering data with a masa_kerja < sysdate the data is still processed, what I want to do is that the data is not processed because the expiration date.

Comment: Perhaps you should first check whether data has expired (i.e. compare MASA_KERJA to SYSDATE). Only if that condition is satisfied, control other conditions.

Comment: do you mean the date comparison logic takes precedence before checking the data is not null ?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I thought that you should first check whether MASA_KERJA is lower than SYSDATE. If so, that row has "expired" so don't do anything. But if it is still "active", then check whether NIK/FULL_NAME/EMAIL is not null and do whatever you're doing.

Comment: okay, thanks for your advice. it really helped me a lot in solving this simple problem